# kubernetes deployment wait between pods on rolling update

Tags: kubernetes

So we have a deployment that is using rolling updates. We need it to pause 180 seconds between each pod it brings up. My understanding is that I need to set `MinReadySeconds: 180` and to set the `RollingUpdateStrategy.MaxUnavailable: 1` and `RollingUpdateStrategy.MaxSurge: 1` for the deployment to wait. With those settings it still brings the pods up as fast as it can. . . What am I missing.

relevant part of my deployment

```
spec:
    minReadySeconds: 180
    replicas: 9
    revisionHistoryLimit: 20
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        deployment: standard
        name: standard-pod
    strategy:
      rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
      type: RollingUpdate
```

Comment: My understanding came for the docs and this closed issue. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27967

Comment: Could you use a readiness check, with a 180 delay start?

Comment: Ill try that and see if that works.

Comment: Solutions go in the space below. Do not edit the question!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a pod is ready after a certain delay is not very idiomatic within an orchestrator like Kubernetes, as there may be something that prevents the pod from successfully starting, or maybe delays the start by another few seconds.

Instead, you could use [Liveliness and Readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) to make sure that the pod is there and ready to serve traffic before taking down the old pod

Comment: the reason we need to space out the pods is because it has to register with an outside service (zookeeper i believe). That outside service can't handle the pods coming up  at the same time.

Comment: The answer still remains the same. Readiness probes should ensure that the pod is ready to serve traffic, which includes checking dependencies if they are required.
Rather than using a non-deterministic input (i.e. a time delay) to infer that we are ready to start a new pod, the readiness probe should check that we have successfully registered with the external service _before_ we mark ourselves as ready. This ensures that even if there is a processing delay on the external service that the pod is registered before starting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

We updated our cluster to a newer version of Kubernetes and it started working.

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker.*</sub>